# Pferde kotzen sehen – warum vor der Apotheke?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Es gibt die Wendung

> Man hat schon Pferde vor der Apotheke kotzen sehen.

Damit wird ausgedrückt, dass man etwas nicht ausschließen sollte, nur weil es unwahrscheinliches ist.

> A: Für die hundertfünfzig Meter zur Schule ziehe ich keinen Fahrradhelm an, da passiert eh nichts.
>   B: Sei dir nicht so sicher, man hat schon Pferde vor der Apotheke kotzen sehen.

Die Wendung kann auch als Kommentar dienen, wenn etwas Verblüffendes eingetreten ist.

> A: Du glaubst es nicht, Gabi und Klaus sind wieder zusammen, nach allem!
>   B: Man hat schon Pferde vor der Apotheke kotzen sehen.

Im Volksmund heißt es, Pferde könnten nicht erbrechen.
Ob das stimmt ist unerheblich – allein die Annahme erklärt diesen Teil des Sprichworts:
Ein Pferd kann nicht kotzen.
Kotzt es dennoch, ist das seltsam.

Das Sprichwort nennt aber als Ort der Übelkeit ausgerechnet den Bereich vor Apotheken.
Ist es besonders unwahrscheinlich – mehr noch als anderswo –, Pferde dort kotzen zu sehen?
Galt etwa ein allgemeines Pferde-Halteverbot vor Apotheken?

**Wie kommt die Apotheke in die Redensart?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die Herleitung ist einfach:

In Ergänzung dessen, dass Pferde sich - anders als Katzen - nicht zu übergeben pflegen, wird es als die Unwahrscheinlichkeit des Ereignisses steigernd dargestellt, wenn solches Erbrechen sich vor einer Apotheke ereignet. Denn wenn das Pferd schon bei der Apotheke war, als ihm schlecht wurde, hätte es ja auch hineingehen und sich ein Medikament kaufen können.

Es handelt sich um eine rhetorische Figur aus der Verwandtschaft des Paradoxons. Man könnte es einen Doppelabsurdismus nennen: Ein Paradoxon (speiendes Pferd) wird um eine weitere Absurdität erweitert (einkaufendes Pferd), um die Absurdität der Situation zu unterstreichen.

Ähnlich:

> Da lachen ja die Hühner auf dem Friedhof

1) Hühner lachen nicht 2) schon gar nicht auf dem Friedhof - denn a) es sind anständige Hühner b) man hält Friedhöfe üblicherweise hühnerfrei.

> Meine Oma fährt im Hühnerstall Motorrad

1) Prototypische Omas fahren nicht Motorrad 2) Im Hühnerstall ist es in der Regel zu eng zum Motorradfahren 3) Tut man es doch, landen die Hühner auf dem Friedhof.

Comment: ... ohne Hupe, ohne Bremse, ohne Licht

Comment: nach Hinzufügen von Punkt 3: aber die lachen dann auch nicht mehr

Comment: Und man kann ja auch nicht annehmen, dass Hühner die Etikette kennen, die man auf dem Friedhof folgen muss...

Comment: @Volker    Willst du sagen: Nur ein totes Huhn ist ein gutes Huhn?

Comment: @ Beta & Christian: Gibt es hier eventuell ein Unterforum zum Rumblödeln? Ich traue mich gerade irgendwie nicht, die 3 bis 4 Erwiederungen, die mir spontan zu Euren Kommentaren durch den Kopf schossen, hier aufzuführen... *ggg*

Comment: @Volker Ja, gibt es: den Chat. Es ist bloß die Frage, wer es dann liest.

Answer (score 9):

Die Annahme, dass Pferde nicht kotzen können ist eben nicht unerheblich für die Redewendung. Pferde sind auf Grund der ihnen gegebenen Peristaltik nicht in der Lage zu "kotzen", da sich die Nahrung bei ihnen nur in eine Richtung bewegen kann. Demnach wäre es wirklich ein sehr seltenes Ereignis ein Pferd kotzen zu sehen.

Der erste Teil der Redewendung "Ich habe schon Pferde kotzen sehen" funktioniert dementsprechend auch alleine und wird meiner Erfahrung nach auch deutlich öfter alleine oder wenigstens gleichberechtigt mit dem zweiten Teil zusammen verwendet.

Der zweite Teil ist eigentlich nichts anderes als eine Verstärkung des ersten Teils. Ist einem Menschen schlecht würde dieser wohl zum Arzt oder zur Apotheke gehen um ein Mittel zu holen. Dieses Verhalten könnte man auch auf das Pferd "antropomorphizieren". Soll das ganze aber einfach noch unwahrscheinlicher klingen lassen.

[SWR](https://www.swr.de/blog/1000antworten/antwort/2570/woher-stammt-die-redewendung-%E2%80%9Eman-hat-schon-pferde-kotzen-sehen/)

[TV Beitrag](https://www.prosieben.de/tv/galileo/videos/2014323-schlaumeier-pferd-vor-der-apotheke-kotzen-sehen-clip)

Comment: Dass Pferde kotzen, ist meines Wissens nicht völlig unmöglich, sondern "nur" sehr unwahrscheinlich. Die Redewendung hat übrigens noch eine zweite Steigerungsstufe, da haben sie nämlich sogar ein Rezept dabei.

Comment: Ich meine: Es ist unerheblich, ob sie wirklich nicht kotzen können oder doch. Es ist nur wichtig, dass *angenommen wird, dass sie es nicht können.*

Comment: @Volker Die Idee mit dem Rezept ist ja großartig. Nur klingt es in meiner Vorstellung etwas holperig formuliert. Hast Du da einen Beleg mit ausformulierter Anwendung?

Comment: Habe ich in mehreren leicht verschiedenen Varianten gehört: "Man hat ja schon Pferde kotzen sehen, vor der Apotheke, mit 'nem Rezept im Maul" bzw. "Man hat ... Apotheke, und sie hatten sogar ein Rezept dabei". Sowohl das Rezept als auch die Apotheke selbst sind mir bisher nur als nachgeschobene Zusätze begegnet.

Comment: Nur als Datenpunkt: sich übergeben bei Pferden ist in der Tat, wie angemerkt duch die Peristaltik "unmöglich". Will heissen, wenn es doch dazu kommt, ist es eine massive Krise - Schlundverstopfung and wasweissich. Massiv ist dann auch die Tierarztrechnung. Bei recht geringen Chancen. :(

Comment: Ich kenne es so: Person 1: "Man hat schon Pferde kotzen sehen." Person 2: "Sogar vor der Apotheke." Darauf antwortet Person 1: "Mit dem Rezept im Maul."